# How does the Nobel committee define literature?

Tags: terminology, awards, definition-of-literature, nobel-prize

As you probably know, Bob Dylan, a musician, was awarded the Nobel prize. [He was the first musician to receive the Nobel prize](https://www.theguardian.com/music/2017/jun/05/bob-dylan-delivers-nobel-prize-literature-lecture-just-in-time).

The Nobel committee, notably, seemed to avoid the word music when explaining why the prize was awarded. The press release simply states that the prize was awarded to Dylan "for having created new poetic expressions within the great American song tradition", i.e. that the committee is awarding the prize based on Dylan's ability as a poet. Sara Danius, Permanent Secretary of the Swedish Academy, described Dylan as a "great poet in the English tradition"; a poet, not a songwriter. And Danius also said that Dylan "should be read"; that's an odd statement to say about a musician, whose works are intended to be listened to.

All of this made me wonder: how does the Nobel committee define literature? I suspect that they describe Dylan as a poet because they consider poetry literature. But I then decided to look for a explanation for where exactly they draw the line, but I wasn't able to find one.

How does the Nobel committee define literature?

Comment: What makes you think they have a *definition* of literature, rather than simply "I know it when I see it"? (As a mathematician, I always want rigorous definitions of terminology, but I've come to accept that outside of maths many terms *have* no properly rigorous definitions.)

Comment: @Rand if they don't have a rigorous definition of literature, then that would make for an answer, wouldn't it? But I suspect that they do have some sort of idea, even if it's not rigorous. They're very reluctant to describe Bob Dylan's work as music, for example. There is, to me, clearly some sort of boundary involved here.

Comment: I'm rather amused that a question asking for the definition of a term as used by some committee is not a question about terminology. I've to retract my upvote since now I have no idea what this question is about.

Comment: @muru this is not worth arguing about, so I rolled it back.

Comment: It's not worth arguing about, but it is worth discussing, because Rand raises an interesting point that leads to alternate formulation: how does the committee decide what works to consider when evaluating candidates? That would a) include the definition of literature if they use "works of literature" as a criterion, b) make the terminology tag inapplicable, c) if they don't explicitly set literature as a requirement, but some other criteria, then an answer listing those would be more useful and d) also make the main concern of your question as listed in the edit summary clearer

Comment: @Muru I mean, there already is https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/3340/how-and-why-did-the-swedish-academy-decide-to-award-bob-dylan-a-nobel-prize, where people can list all of the criteria involved in selecting the nobel prize winner. I'm interested in one aspect of this: does a definition of literature play a role in the selection, and if so, what role. (I suspect it does because the comittee was reluctent to describe Dylan's work as music, but that's just a suspicion--I'm looking for answers to confirm or deny my suspicion). Maybe the question could be edited to make this clear.

Comment: @Hamlet that's slightly different - it's asking what the criteria for selecting a *winner* are, and my alternate question is asking what the criteria for deciding which *works* of a candidate to consider are.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How and why did the Swedish Academy decide to award Bob Dylan a Nobel Prize?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/3340/how-and-why-did-the-swedish-academy-decide-to-award-bob-dylan-a-nobel-prize)

Comment: I could see an argument for there being a difference, though, so I could be wrong on that.

Comment: @EJoshuaS in my mind it isn't. Yes, I asked the question because the prize was awarded to Dylan. But this is about a specific criteria used to nominate/award prizes--the nobel comittee's definition of literature. Note that none of the answers to that question talk about definitions of literature, which is what I'm interested in.

Comment: Fair point - I'll retract my dupe vote, then, because I agree that the answer there doesn't exactly answer that.